# Xcode can jump to the #define of c stand lib

Tags: c, xcode, xcode5

i use xcode to write a c command line program,but i found the jump to define is not work well for the stand lib,i record a picture to show what happen,is that normal with xcode?

[image: it cant jump the define of the limits.h]

```
            //
            //  main.c
            //  0.4 xCodecantjump
            //
            //  Created by Sen on 14-5-19.
            //  Copyright (c) 2014年 SLboat. All rights reserved.
            //

            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <limits.h>
            #include "main.h"

            int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
            {
                int a = INT_MAX;
                int c = INT_MIN;
                int b = START;
                // insert code here...
                printf("some int: %d, %d, %d\n", a, c ,b);
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you make no sense, and your illustration is jumping around like a grasshopper.  Are you complaining about the editor, compiler errors (if so, what are they?), or runtime problems?  ("Jump to the #define" makes no sense.)

Comment: @HotLicks OP couldn't be more clear, there is even a video(!) showing the problem. *jump to define* seems like a good synonym for *go to definition*.

Comment: No its not normal. I cmd-click on INT_MIN and I'm taken to line 68 of limits.h (Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)).

Comment: @self. - The "video" is just a bunch of jumbled images.

Comment: @HotLicks The images presented in the sequence actually represent a video of the problem. It is also called a [gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format). http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif/200px-Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif blows your mind!

Comment: @self. And it's unintelligible.

Comment: @slboat Don't worry, your question is perfectly fine.

Comment: +1 for video demonstration!

Comment: @WhozCraig i using the xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008) too,not work function.

Comment: @self. thank you!and sorry not make a so clean picture,i Record it use  LiceCAP

Comment: @slboat its fine. I particularly liked the name you gave your header fencepost (though I only see it for a split-second): `__4_Xcode_cant_jump_h`. But you should know that identifier is implementation reserved. Use an application/project preamble, like `MYAPP_Header_Blah_h`, and *no double underscores*. There are rules about preprocessor macro names, and *plenty* of questions and answers on the subject on this forum. DO some hunting to discover them. I realize its just a test thing on your side, but in case you didn't know.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you!after i change the name,it still wont jump,but i will try avoid use this kind project name anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is some kind of ObjC optimization.

[image: Preprocess result]

Switching to C++ Source compilation solved this problem (with rebuild).

[image: select C++ Source in the info tab (on the right)]

Comment: it's great!you are right,i switch it to c++ source,and clean it,then rebuild,it worked!

Comment: but that's just seems so wired...i tried the obj-c source it's seems cant found it too.